# How do I handle objects generated by a Runnable?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app which generates numbers by using some *Runnable* (inside a certain *MainActivity*). I am trying to obtain the exponential moving average of these numbers and display it in a *TextView*. What is a correct way to handle that? A straightforward approach produces NaN's, by whatever reason. I have just a week worth of experience with both Java and Android, and so the situation puzzles me greatly.

Comment: Sounds like you have made an attempt but it's not working like you want. Perhaps if you post a [mcve] someone will be able to make a suggestion how to fix it.

Comment: I am asking about a general principle, and a code could be any in which objects of the above types are present. Generally, how, when, and where to declare a variable which depends on a sequence of objects generated by a Runnable.

Comment: Your code there, even as a generic question, would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to jump the synchronicity gap.

There are various approaches. I'll mention the easiest one, which requires a Runnable to know it is the last one being `run()`.

In that case, store all your results in a variable which is in the outer scope from the Runnable. The last Runnable to run works out and outputs your aggregate function.

```
final List<Number> myNumbers = ...
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ...
        myNumbers.add(partialResult);
        if (iAmTheLastRunStanding()) {
            aggregateAndOutput(myNumbers);
        }
    }
}
...
myRunnable.run();
...
myRunnable.run();
...
```

Comment: myTextView.setText(exponentialMovingAverage(myNumbers));

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel Should you really be accessing the text view widget in the GUI from a background thread?

Comment: Yes, you probably want to use the Android equivalent of JavaFX's Platform.runLater(runnable). But I might be wrong, I don't know Android